# C++ How to take from first vector X1 first elements, from second vector X2 first elements etc

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++17

I have N vectors and I need to take from first vector X1 first elements, from second vector X2 first elements etc. I need to do this repeatedly, until I fill result vector with K elements. There are two solutions which came to my mind:

1. Keep vector of N iterators (one iterator for each vector) and return (iterator, iterator + X) range and keep as a member of class which stores these vectors an index of currently processed vector.
2. Keep index of currently processed vector, copy from it first X elements, remove these elements from vector and return them. I like this solution, but I think it's too slow.

Is there any other way to do it?

EDIT: 
Example:

I have vector of vectors:

```
{ {12, 14, 17, 2, 89, 34, 6, ...}, 
  {1, 4, 9, 5, 9, 41, 99, ...}, 
  {90, 76, 44, 21, 55, 45, 79, ...} }
```

I want to take repeadly from first vector 3 elements, from second 1 element and from third 4 elements and put them into result vector unitl size of that vector doesn't reach 10. So, result vector would look like this:

```
{ 12, 14, 17, 1, 90, 76, 44, 21, 2, 89 }
```

Hope this clear all confusion.
Thanks!

Comment: As for me then I have not understood what is required.

Comment: Are all of these vector stored separately or are they in something?

Comment: Those vectors are stored in vector (yes, it's vector of vectors)

Comment: Then why don't you just loop through the vector?

Comment: And how to keep track from where I should start taking next X1 elements?

Comment: You keep a counter.  If you take 10 elements from the first vector then you start on the second vector at `begin() + 10`

Comment: An example of input data and desired output data would help clarify what you are asking for

Comment: There's no substantial difference between the two approaches. The one with removal is less efficient but you can work around this if you really want to (e.g. reverse all vectors and start from the end of each, i.e. rbegin()).

Comment: @n.m. is right. If you don't care what happens to the input, don't bother removing elements. If you do care, then one method is correct, and the other is wrong.